# Updating your game with new variables

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a game where I am loading my variables from table that is stored as a .json file. When user plays the game for the first time, a table will be created with default variables, looking something like this:

```
GameState = {highscore = 0, musicon = true}
```

This .json file will be created ONLY ONCE (when user first plays the game). Upon playing, those variables will change and when the user decides to exit app, those variables will be saved to a .json file. Table might look something like this now:

```
GameState = {highscore = 5, musicon = false}
```

When user starts the game again, those variables will be loaded and the player can continue as he never left the game.

However, as I am updating my game, that default table will have some new variables in it. Example:

```
v1.0 table 
GameState = {highscore = 0, musicon = true}

v1.1 table
GameState = {highscore = 0, musicon = true, volume = 100}
```

Since a player with `v1.0` game has a table that looks like this: `GameState = {highscore = 0, musicon = true}`, he will be missing that `volume` upon updating the game to `v1.1` causing the game to crash.

Here's my question: How can I make it so that, when the user has updated the game, also update his .json file (table) with new variables added in the new update while keeping his old scores, settings etc.? I've been struggling with this for a few days now and I can't do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the keyword `or` to initialize a value if it isn't already present.
For example:

```
GameStat.volume = GameStat.volume or 100
```

`or` returns its first value if it isn't `false` or `nil`, otherwise it returns its second value.

Comment: You, sir, deserve a medal! Thank you so much!